# "В лаптях" — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: *в л**а**птях* или *в лапт**я**х?*

Comment: В словари не заглядывали?

Comment: Нашёл в Викисловаря, что правильно на Я, но хочется почему-то сказать на А. Может быть, по аналогии с "не в дЕньгах счастье".

Answer (score 3):

1) ла́поть (обувь) — существительное, мужской род, неодушевлённое, 2-е склонение;
2) ла́поть(о невежественном человеке) — существительное, мужской род, одушевлённое, 2-е склонение.

И.  ла́поть,    ла́пти
Р.  ла́птя, лапте́й
Д.  ла́птю, лаптя́м
В. (неодуш.)    ла́поть,    ла́пти
В. (одуш.)  ла́птя  лапте́й
Т.  ла́птем,    лаптя́ми
**П.    ла́пте, лаптя́х**
([Грамматический словарь](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C))

Ла́пти, лапте́й (другие формы не приведены, поэтому в остальных падежах (кроме винительного) ударение падает тоже на последний слог — (о) **лаптя́х**).
([Н. Еськова. Словарь трудностей русского языка. Ударение. Грамматические формы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=wlPmzlybW_&sig=ACfU3U2cc8eAxJxxkb7qMcjFMrNliLKJeQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi14enYysTjAhXCKVAKHT2sAJMQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false)

Бог грудей и <...> отвислых,
Бог **лапте́й** и пухлых ног,
Горьких лиц и сливок кислых,
вот он, вот он русский бог.
(П. А. Вяземский. Русский бог)

Картуз на затылок надвинул,
**Лаптя́ми** взвевая ленивую пыль.
Лицо запрокинул,
К губам прижимая бутыль.
(А. Белый. Осинка)

Пеной рос заря туманится,
Словно глубь очей невестиных.
Прибрела весна, как странница,
С посошком **в лаптя́х** берестяных.
(С. Есенин)

[А. Зализняк. Древнерусское ударение](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5TKdCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA567&lpg=PA567&dq=%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=s8lrZRKVU4&sig=ACfU3U0Exm7imCLsjoHVhwjxlgz-vVEAzA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi14enYysTjAhXCKVAKHT2sAJMQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false):
**ла́поть** — а о С — 347«—» Алф. (ла́пти 167) [+Букв. Ал.], Колм. (в ... ла́птях” 37) [*ср. произв.* ла́потникъ].

В ла́птях — это ударение устарело, сегодня правильно говорить **в лаптя́х.**

Comment: Спасибо большое! Значит, всё-таки говорили так. ;)

Comment: А как узнать, что говорили? Обычно ненормативная форма определяется по стихотворной речи (для этого нужны примеры) или бывают пометки в орфоэпических словарях "неправ!." Но вот у Даля: Правда в лаптях; а кривда, хоть и в кривых, да в сапогах. Не осуди в лаптях, сапоги в санях, говорит гость шутя.

Comment: Если "в лаптях — в санях" должна быть рифма, тогда, может, действительно не говорили и моё желание ничем не оправдано...