# «Выглушить», «житейство» — есть ли такие слова?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Существуют ли такие слова, как "выглушить", "житейство"?

Comment: Смысл этих слов обозначьте, пожалуйста!

Comment: А в Интернете вы смотрели? Просто набираете слова в любом поисковом сервисе и получаете ответ. Обычно здесь задаются такие вопросы,  на которые найти информацию  не удалось

Comment: "Обычно здесь задаются такие вопросы, на которые найти информацию не удалось". Разве?! Вот совсем недавно был вопрос от участника с большим рейтингом (“В лаптях” — ударение). https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453669/%d0%92-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5 На этот вопрос тоже не надо было отвечать? Или это позиция — только для шпыняния новеньких? Несправедливо.

Comment: V. Lilla  Вы мне нравитесь и Ваши ответы тоже. Мне приятно, что Вы активно начали работать на форуме, такие люди нам нужны, так как отвечающих постоянно не так много.  Но разве Вы задали этот вопрос? И разве Владимир - новенький? Качество Вашего ответа высокое, а вот качество вопроса - низкое. Почему задан один вопрос по двум словам - это не по правилам. Почему эти слова вызвали интерес у участника, какую информацию он сам нашел и что хочет уточнить. Впрочем, я, пожалуй, спрошу у модераторов, может быть, они одобрят его вопросы и Ваши замечания.

Comment: У новенького на этот момент борода 514 мм.

Comment: Что касается вопроса "В лаптях — ударение", то вопросы о постановке ударения никогда не бывают лишними. Если существуют две формы, то интересно как они соотносятся между собой. Даже в словари разных годов заглянуть интересно. Так что на такой вопрос всегда можно ответить интересно.

Answer (score 0):

*Выглушить* есть, относится к неумеренному употреблению спиртных напитков. См. [викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C). Там ещё упоминается вариант с рыбой, но он вызывает сомнения.

*Житейство* употребляется в паре стихотворений малоизвестных поэтов, но это скорее из области словесных экспериментов в стиле Маяковского и прочих. Лично я считаю, что это нормальным словоупотреблением считать нельзя, и такого слова нет.

Comment: А где, на каком сервисе вы посмотрели случаи употребления житейства? Можете порекомендовать?

Comment: @Владимир, да в [гугле](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=HZ01XbPZLNGHwPAP2O-eoA8&q="Житейство"&oq="Житейство") же. Сейчас опять посмотрел - оказалось оно довольно активно употребляется, хотя словари его и не знают. Я лично его никогда не встречал, видимо это местечковое слово. Литературные ссылки в другом ответе на самиздатовские произведения, похоже.

Comment: Не самиздат это, а "Великорусские сказки в записях И. А. Худякова" ("Анастасья Прекрасная и Иван — русский богатырь": https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/hudyakov/text.pdf стр. 95).

Comment: @V. Lilla, верно, меня смутил сайт литмир. Но всё же согласитесь, народные сказки мало подходят на роль эталона литературного языка.

Comment: Дело ведь не в эталоне, а в вопросе: "Существуют ли такие слова?.." Ответ: они "еще как" существуют — пусть и не в строго литературной (зафиксированной словарями) речи. Чем же плох сказочный язык?

Comment: Подобные слова существуют в региональных _говорах_ (диалектах), из источника по вашей ссылке следует только это, поскольку сказки записывались в таких местах как село Мишкино Зарайского уезда Рязанской губернии и др. В широком употреблении их нет, несмотря на возможность словообразования по типичным схемам (семейство - житейство), вероятно, потому, что от этого не возникает новых полезных смыслов. Слово "выглушить" (рыбу в неком водоёме) мне кажется неблагозвучным и неясным по сравнению с очевидным "переглушить" (я сначала написал, затем заглянул в словарь у без удивления там его увидел).

Comment: В значении "выпить залпом" это слово иногда употребляется по как гибрид от "глушить водку/пиво" и "выпить залпом", что тоже не очень изящно, а "житейство", как  выясняется, в некоторых местностях попросту заменяет слово "житьё", причём непосвящённым догадаться об этом без контекста невозможно.

Comment: Такое чувство, что Вы не читаете чужие ответы (и ссылки в них).Село Мишкино ведь не единственное, где есть употребление. И вопрос ведь был не в том — насколько слова изящны или благозвучны.

Comment: @V. Lilla, когда обращаетесь к кому-то в комментариях, используйте конструкцию _@имя_, пожалуйста. Иначе это увидит только автор ответа, а вы же ответили явно не мне. Впрочем, я с Alex_ander полностью согласен - диалектные слова все-таки не относятся к основному массиву языка.

Comment: @freim Слушаюсь! Но я к Вам и не обращалась. Alex_ander адресовал комментарий мне, а я — ему (если я правильно вижу и оцениваю, потому что нет никаких "@" при обращении-ответе). P. S. А причем здесь "основной массив языка"? Вопрос был  — слова ЕСТЬ или НЕТ?

Comment: @V. Lilla, вы оба обращались ко мне. Если нет @ с именем, то извещение придёт только автору ответа (мне в данном случае). Ваш последний ответ Alex_ander не увидел, разве что специально зашёл сюда посмотреть не ответил ли кто ему.